# Hide Querystring in MVC action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, query-string

I want to hide the Querystring into My controller's action.

In my application scenariois something like this:

1) 
   I have opened new action into new Window as:

```
var check="Particular String"
var url = rootUrl("Home/Preview?Docs=" + check);
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

2) On controller's Side I have used some code into Controller's action as:

```
 public ActionResult Preview(string Docs)
        {
            TempData["Docs"] = Docs;
            return RedirectToAction("UnInvoicedPreview");
        }
```

My Query::  1) when opening new window it shows the Query string in the Begining(uptill when it doesn't redirects to another action).

2) I dont want to show that QueryString into the URL.

3) Is there any way to hide the Query string or can we Encrypt that?

Comment: **WHY** do you want to Encrypt or Hide the QueryString?

Comment: @Erik Philips Because it shows the IDs which is posted into Querystring.
I have to hide it because of the Security Purpose.

Answer (score 4):

no you cannot hide querystring at all.
instead of that there is many method 
1. `session["key"]` 
2. `viewbag` 
3. `$.post in jquery` 
4.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Preview(string Docs)
{
    TempData["Docs"] = Docs;
     return RedirectToAction("UnInvoicedPreview");
}
```

Comment: can I assign value into Session variable as  
@Session["_UninvoicedDocuments"]=check;

Its not working & throws exceptions.

Comment: @RahulRJ where it is throwing exception in `view` or in `controller` while fetching value

Comment: into Jquery of View I am using particular code like ::

var check="SomeString";
@Session["_UninvoicedDocuments"]=check;

Comment: @RahulRJ try setting like this `@{Session["_UninvoicedDocuments"] = "check";}`

Comment: @Nilesh its not working. And 'check' is a Variable not a string in which I have stored Confidential IDs in concatenated string format,
so your answer is not working

Comment: You may want to remove post, as it won't help for security purposes.  (Per new comments)

Comment: @RahulRJ you use @httpcontext.current.session["key"] in view, but instead of that use @viewbag["key"]

Comment: @MaTya `@httpcontext.current.session["key"]` is same as `@Session["key"]` you dont have to write entire reference and also it is `@HttpContext.Current.Session["key"]` not `@httpcontext.current.session["key"]`

Comment: @ Nilesh you canot write @session[""] in view if you not import @using HttpContext; i knw it is same i think RahulRj code not working becoz he has not import it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can store data in session variables or try storing values in cookies.
2. It would be better to use TempData, which only allows the value to be used once (removed on first access). However, this implies the value will be used almost immediately.
3. encrypt the querystring.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very good MVC. MVC doesn't really use querystrings, except in special cases.

Suggested Url in MVC would be "/Home/Preview/<docsValue>"

That being said, if you want to hide the parameter, best to use jQuery and do a post to server.

```
var check="Particular String"
var data = "Docs=" + check;
$.post("/Home/Preview", data);
```

Note you can still see this value if you look at the view source of the page, but at least it won't show in the Url.

Comment: You may want to remove post, as it won't help for security purposes. (Per new comments)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` and `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode` to convert byte array to URL-safe string

Answer (score 0):

Embed your page or portion of the page in IFrame this will hide the query string and URL altogether.

Comment: You may want to remove IFrame, as it won't help for security purposes. (Per new comments)