# How to hide parameters of URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

My current url is `/Product/Create?date=5/7/2014%2012:00:00%20AM`

Actually I want like this: /Product/Create

My sample code is :

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create(DateTime date)
    {
        ViewBag.Date = date;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Any one can help me?

Comment: Use post rather than Get. It will help you to hide all parameters.

Comment: could you please check this below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637732/url-rewriting-in-mvc3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide Querystring in MVC action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129954/hide-querystring-in-mvc-action)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HttpPost` to force this:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(DateTime date)
    {
        ViewBag.Date = date;
        return View();
    }
}
```

And when calling the action you need to submit it via a form-post. If you show us the code how you call it we can help you there...

The `HttpPost` attribut will force you to use "post" - if you still want the "other option" possible you can leave the attribute away and just use "post" for your desired case.

UPDATE:
You need to call the action like:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Hidden("date", DateTime.Now.ToString())
    <input type="submit" value="create">
}
```

To your current code `<a href="/Product/Create?date=@DateTime.Now.Date">`:
This creates a GET request and even if you want that you should do it like the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Product", new { date = DateTime.Now.ToString() })
```

This will take the proper routing in account and create a valid link.

Using e.g. `JQuery` you can do the follwoing to have a link if JS is enabled:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("date", DateTime.Now.ToString())
    <input id="myFormSubmit" type="submit" value="create">
    <a id="myFormLink" href="#" style="display: none;" onclick="$('#myForm').submit(); return false;">create</a>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myFormLink').show();
        $('#myFormSubmit').hide();
    });
<script>
```

Comment: Who said this is a POST? This could be a GET for a view which takes a parameter.

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Product/Create

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18055

Comment: Thanks for your support, any other solution?

Comment: i called like this: <a href="/Product/Create?date=@DateTime.Now.Date">

Comment: I want to hide the query string by routing, Is it possible?

Comment: If you set the `HttpPost` and use `@Html.ActionLink` it should not create GET links anymore, but I am nor 100% sure about that. But in the end you can not use a "simple link" and POST together...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is infact a GET request for a view which requires a `Date` parameter (for whatever reason) I'd say your best bet is to pass the information as a custom header in the request

```
GET /Products/Create HTTP/1.1
X-YourApp-Date: 2014-07-05T12:00:00
```

Your action would then look like

```
public ActionResult Create() <-- no parameters
{
    ViewBag.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Headers["X-YourApp-Date"], 
        "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return View();
}
```

Some side notes

- It's generally best to work with dates as UTC and not as Local (however it really depends on the circumstance)
- If the date is important or used in anyway related to security then you should probably encrypt it.
- If you are passing it up as a string use a **consistent format** and stick with it, this makes it easier when it comes to server-side parsing (see example)

Comment: +1 for not switching verbs just to make a URL prettier.

Comment: But how would you add this header value using a link on your page? (See his comment on my answer - he is using an `<a />` tag at the moment)

Comment: @chrfin the OP wasn't clear on that when I posted my answer. Given they are just looking to use a link it's obviously not as simple. It can be done though, will just require a bit more work on the client side. When I get some time I will post a full solution.

Comment: @James: That would be great, as I like your solution and could use that sometimes too...

Comment: I want to hide the query string by routing, Is it possible?

Comment: @Salih yes (and no). Technically the solution would be to perform the GET request via AJAX, pull down the page, and then update the client content/URL (similar to he behaviour of a [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)).

Answer (score 1):

In addition with controller change to handle only POST requests

```
...
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(DateTime date)
...
```

You also have to change code for calling action in markup from link to something like

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { style = "display:inline" })) {
    @Html.Hidden("date", DateTime.Now.ToString())
    <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.submit(); return false">Whatever</a>
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this only works WITH JavaScript. You should provide a "default submit fallback"...

Comment: I added a possible solution for this to my answer. If JS is a requirement for your page anyhow you can keep this version as it is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

In JS:

```
window.history.pushState("", "", "/Product/Create");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please put the description with your codes and explain how this code solves the problem.